# Filter pandas column with current row values and sum another column to form a new column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

and I have the following dataset.

| Date | Area | Value | Delivery_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | ABC | 10 | 02-01-2021 |
| 02-01-2021 | BCD | 20 | 04-01-2021 |
| 03-01-2021 | ABC | 15 | 04-01-2021 |
| 04-01-2021 | BCD | 25 | 05-01-2021 |
| 05-01-2021 | ABC | 15 | 06-01-2021 |

I have to create a new column named Sum which follows following conditions.

It should take the current row and should look for values from other rows which has same Area and date greater than current row date and delivery date greater than current row "date" as well. It should sum up the values from rows which meet these three conditions. So the resulting table will look like

| Date | Area | Value | Delivery_Date | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | ABC | 10 | 02-01-2021 | 40 |
| 02-01-2021 | BCD | 20 | 04-01-2021 | 45 |
| 03-01-2021 | ABC | 15 | 04-01-2021 | 30 |
| 04-01-2021 | BCD | 25 | 05-01-2021 | 25 |
| 05-01-2021 | ABC | 15 | 06-01-2021 | 15 |

I am not sure how to start. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use a [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html)+[`expanding.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.sum.html) after sorting the data on the dates (recent to ancient):

```
# ensure datetime (although this format could be also sorted as string)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['sum'] = (df
 .sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)      # reverse values
 .groupby(['Area'])['Value'].expanding().sum() # sum recent values
 .droplevel(0)
)
```

output:

```
        Date Area  Value   sum
0 2021-01-01  ABC     10  40.0
1 2021-02-01  BCD     20  45.0
2 2021-03-01  ABC     15  30.0
3 2021-04-01  BCD     25  25.0
4 2021-05-01  ABC     15  15.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. Just a small question. Say if I have another date column named delivery date. How would you go about filtering out the rows for summation when one would like the delivery date greater than the current date. I have updated the question for this.

Comment: you can filter using `df.loc[df['Delivery_Date']>df['Date']]` (assuming datetime types here)